# First variation of area and some open questions

Tags: analysis

I am studying the first variation of area: Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ open und $u:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ $C^2-$ smooth. Further let $\eta \in C_c^{\infty}\Omega$, compacted supported in $\Omega$. Then we have:

$$\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}Area(\Gamma_{u+t\eta})=\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}\int_{\Omega}\sqrt{1+\nabla(u+t\eta)^2}=\int_{\Omega}\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}\sqrt{ 1+\nabla(u+t\eta)^2}=\int_{\Omega}\frac{<\nabla u, \nabla \eta>}{\sqrt{1+\nabla(u)^2}}=-\int_{\Omega}\eta div(\frac{\nabla u}{\sqrt{1+\nabla(u)^2}})$$

My questions now are :

1. Why can we interchange the integral and the derivative?
2. How do we get the last equality? I don't see how the minus occurs and what did we used there?

Many thanks for more details about these parts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your integration variable is $x$. You are taking the derivative with respect to a parameter $t$. Since your integrand is a smooth function of $t$ and your domain $\Omega$ is fixed, you can bring the derivative inside the integral (look up Leibniz rule or differentiation under the integral sign)
2. The last equality is obtained integrating by parts. Ne non-integral term vanishes because $\eta=0$ on the boundary of $\Omega$. Namely,
   $$
   \int_{\Omega}\frac{\nabla u}{\sqrt{1+\nabla(u)^2}}\cdot\nabla \eta\,dx=\int_{\Omega}\left[div\left(\eta \frac{\nabla u}{\sqrt{1+\nabla(u)^2}}\right)-\eta\,div \frac{\nabla u}{\sqrt{1+\nabla(u)^2}}\right]\,dx=
   $$

$$
=\int_{\Omega}div\left(\eta \frac{\nabla u}{\sqrt{1+\nabla(u)^2}}\right)\,dx-\int_\Omega\eta\,div \frac{\nabla u}{\sqrt{1+\nabla(u)^2}}\,dx=
$$

$$
=\int_{\partial\Omega}\eta \frac{\nabla u}{\sqrt{1+\nabla(u)^2}}\cdot dS-\int_\Omega\eta\,div \frac{\nabla u}{\sqrt{1+\nabla(u)^2}}\,dx
$$

where, in the first line, the identity
$$
\nabla\cdot (\phi\mathbf{V})=\phi\nabla\cdot\mathbf{V}+\nabla\phi\cdot \mathbf{V},
$$
valid for smooth scalar fields $\phi$ and vector fields $\mathbf{V}$, has been applied, while the divergence theorem has been applied from the second to the third lines. The surface integral vanishes because $\eta=0$ on $\partial\Omega$. So you are left with the second.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! In part 2) I don't understand how exactly the integration by parts is here applied.. Would it be possible to give some more details?

Comment: I just added details to my answer.